# Delete comments within a range - vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

is there a way I can delete any comments found within a range in Word vba?

As part of a larger macro, I have this section:

```
For i = 0 To max

With Selection
 .Find.ClearFormatting
 .Find.Text = myarray(i)
 .Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Do While .Find.Execute(Forward:=True) = True
 For Each com In .Comments
com.DeleteRecursively
Next com
.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
Loop
```

I have also tried `For Each com in .range.comments`. Unfortunately this doesn't really work and is just deleting every comment in the document, but I only want it to delete comments added to text within the found text (the search terms defined by myarray(i)). Is there any way to do this?

Equally, the `.range.highlightcolorindex = wdnohighlight` line is only working where i > 0, so highlights are not being removed for the first term searched but are being removed for subsequent search terms. Any help with this issue would also be much appreciated.

Comment: Use the Reference.Start property of the comments, and compare it with your Selection Start and End properties.

Comment: Would that involve cycling through every comment in the document and checking its property? I'm working on documents with hundreds of comments in them so I'm concerned that would significantly slow the process

Comment: Yes, but do a try.